# How to show convergence in probability of $X_{n} = g(b_{n})$ to $X = g(b)$.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

As a general method, how does one show convergence in probability: $P(|X_{n} - X| > a)$ going to 0, for all $a > 0$, for the following: $X$ is a function if a parameter: e.g. $X = b(1-b)$ with $0 < b < 1$ and we estimate $X$ with $X_{n}$ where $X_{n}$ = $b_{n}(1-b_{n})$ and $b_{n}$ is itself an estimate of unknown parameter $b$, i.e. $b_{n}$ is the average of independent Bernoulli($b$) observations?

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and $B_n\to B$ in probability then $X_n=g(B_n)\to X=g(B)$ in probability. Is this your question?

Comment: Yes indeed, this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general fact: If $g$ is continuous, $X_n=g(B_n)$, $X=g(B)$, and $B_n\to B$ in probability, then $X_n\to X$ in probability.